# Htaccess rewrite when folder is in url

Tags: .htaccess, directory, find, rename

I need a rules that find a folder in my url and rewrite folder before.

Example:

`www.site.it/folder1/sub1/detail/page.html` => 
`www.site.it/newfolder/sub1/detail/page.html`

`www.site.it/folder2/sub1/detail/page2.html` => `www.site.it/newfolder/sub1/detail/page2.html`

`www.site.it/folder1/fodler2/sub1/detail/page3.html` => `www.site.it/newfolder/sub1/detail/page3.html`

Comment: Please reformat your question in a way that it asks a specific question instead of asking others to work for you and get things done for you. This way, it might be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/sub1/(.*)$ /newfolder/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).